# COM object releasing function gives error when passing a "IUnknown * &" as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, com, pass-by-reference, directx-9

In a header, following code is included.

```
inline void SafeRelease( IUnknown * & in_COM_Pointer )
    {
        if ( NULL != in_COM_Pointer )
        {
            in_COM_Pointer->Release();
            in_COM_Pointer = NULL;
        }
    }
```

When It is used as given below,

```
SafeRelease(_D3DDevice); // _D3DDevice is a "IDirect3DDevice9 *". According to documentation it is inherited from "IUnknown".
```

It gives a compilation error:

> error C2664: 'SafeRelease' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'IDirect3DDevice9 *' to 'IUnknown *&'

I know how to write this function using templates or macros. But I want to know why this happens.

1. Why does this give error?
2. How to write it correctly?
3. If inheritance cannot be used for writing this function should I use templates?
4. Anything that I would have to be careful about when implementing it using suggested method?

Comment: Since the same answer is replicated (several times) below, I'm dropping mine and simply asking that you [**read this document**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are reasons *not* to do what you're trying, and rather than proctor yet-another boilerplate of a better way to do something you shouldn't be doing in the first place, you may want to consider alternatives. The very pattern you're attempting is called out within the linked article, caveats and all.

Comment: Thank you for the nice link :). I am actually trying to measure the performance gap between smart pointers and this implementation for a small graphical simulation. BTW the article suggests passing a pointer-to-pointer while they can pass a pointer-by-reference. That is bad, isn't it.

Comment: If you're referring to the article's implementation of `SafeRelease`, it ultimately suggests you simply don't do it at all if you're coding in C++ (and you are). By the time inlining is finished I'd be surprised if the `SafeRelease` pattern has *any* edge on smart pointers without violating fundamental COM rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **” 1.** Why does this give error?

Consider this:

```
struct Animal {};
struct Dog: Animal { void bark() {} };
struct Dolphin: Animal { void dive() {} };

void foo( Animal*& p ) { p = new Dolphin(); }

auto main() -> int
{
    Dog* p = new Dog();
    foo( p );             //! C2664, Would have changed p to point to Dolphin.
    p->bark();            // Uh huh...
}
```

So, this is not permitted.

There’s more of the same, e.g. regarding deep `const`-ness of actual versus formal argument, and it’s generally known as the Liskov Substitution Principle, the LSP, after Barbara Liskov.

---

> **” 2.** How to write it correctly?

One solution for the general problem, as [Hans Passant has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219172/464581), is to use templating in order to deal directly with the type or types at hand, no conversion.

In this concrete case, however, as long as you’re sure that you don’t have a nullpointer, just call `p->Release()` instead of `SafeRelease( p )`.

---

> **” 3.** If inheritance cannot be used for writing this function should I use templates?

You can use templating but it’s not necessary; see above.

---

> **” 4.** Anything that I would have to be careful about when implementing it using suggested method?

The suggested method involves an envisioned implicit conversion `Derived*` → `Base*` for COM interface pointers.

Do note that while `Derived*` → `Base*` conversion generally works nicely also with COM interfaces, the `IUnknown` interface is subject to very *special rules*.

Namely, internally a COM object may have multiple `IUnknown` sub-objects, corresponding to possible `IUnknown*` pointers into this object, but only one of these pointer values **identifies** the object.

So when you want an `IUnknown` pointer that identifies the object, a pointer that can be compared to other `IUnknown` pointers to check if it’s the same object, you have to use `QueryInterface` to obtain the `IUnknown` pointer.

Happily you can use `QueryInterface` via any interface pointer that you have, and since this member function is provided via the `IUnknown` interface that all other interfaces inherit, it illustrates that you can use non-identifying `IUnknown` pointers for other purposes than identification.

Answer (score 2):

> <sup>**Note**: To fully grasp the information in this post, some knowledge about [*lvalues and rvalues*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/1090079) is required.</sup>

---

#### Introduction

```
SafeRelease(_D3DDevice); // ill-formed
```

Here we try pass the address of a `_D3DDevice` to *SetRelease*, but it is not callable since it requires an *lvalue* (a reference to) of type *pointer-to-IUnknown*.

Just because *Derived* inherits from *Base*, does not mean that an **lvalue** pointer to *Derived* can be converted to an **lvalue** of type pointer to *Base*.

The implicitly conversion from `Derived*` to `Base*` will yield an **rvalue**.

```
struct A     { };
struct B : A { };

void func (A*&);
```

```
B* p = ...;
func (ptr);      // ill-formed, the implicitly yield `A*` is not an lvalue,
                 //             and rvalues cannot bind to lvalues refernces
```

---

#### What is the *"solution"*?

```
inline void SafeRelease( IUnknown * in_COM_Pointer );
```

```cpp
SafeRelease (&_D3DDevice); // (A)
```

(A) will yield a temporary of type *pointer-to-IDirect3DDevice9*, this pointer can implicitly turn into a *pointer-to-IUnknown* since *IDirect3DDevice9* inherits from *IUnknown*.

We no longer try to form an *lvalue-reference* to the implicitly yield pointer, and the code compiles..

---

#### Implications

... but, this also means that we will be unable to update the value of any pointer argument passed in, so if that is an requirement you have/should resort to using templates so that you can get a reference to the actual value passed as argument.

```
template<typename T>
inline void SafeRelease(T * & in_COM_Pointer);
```

Comment: With this technical solution the purpose of `SafeRelease`, of nulling the argument pointer variable, is no longer met: the function has become ~meaningless.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I thought it was clear that such a "purpose" is ill-formed with the current approach, given what is written in the post. **Edit:** see updated post for clearification.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Did you mean `IUnknown * * in_COM_Pointer` ?

Comment: The `&_D3DDevice` forms a pointer to pointer. Quoting the question, "_D3DDevice is a "IDirect3DDevice9 *". Also as already mentioned, the attempted solution in this answer throws out the baby with the bathwater (no matter that one may rightfully consider this particular baby to be of negative value).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf post fixed, thanks for letting me know. As stated in the question the *"solution"* of being able to call the function has the impliciation of not being able to modify the argument that the function is being invoked with. The description is there since OP explicitly asked for one in his question.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: Look at Hans Passant's answer or my answer for how to enable calling while keeping the purpose. Not that I agree with that purpose, which IMHO is mainly a negative utility Microsoft coding environment convention, like Hungarian notation or `T` macros. But without that purpose it doesn't make much sense to have the function at all.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf such a template declaration is included in my post, and wording about why that is neccessary.

Comment: well *now* it does ;-)

Answer (score 2):

COM does not permit casting interface pointers, you **must** use QueryInterface().  This is enforced by the C++ compiler.  Like this:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : /*public*/ Base {};

inline void SafeRelease(Base* & ptr) {}

void test() {
    auto p = new Derived;
    SafeRelease(p);      // C2664
}
```

You can do it with a template function:

```
template<typename T>
inline void SafeRelease(T * & in_COM_Pointer) {
    if (NULL != in_COM_Pointer) {
        in_COM_Pointer->Release();
        in_COM_Pointer = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 would be even better with explanation of how if the OP's call was permitted it would enable storing a pointer to different unrelated type in the actual argument variable (maybe with mention of LSP).

Answer (score 1):

`IDirect3DDevice9` is inherited from `IUnknown` but it is not exactly `IUnknown`. This makes `IDirect3DDevice9*` variable incompatible with `IUnknown*&` argument.

Hence, you need to either cast between types, or use a more flexible releasing function, template based, e.g.:

```
template <typename IFoo>
VOID SafeRelease(IFoo*& pFoo)
{
    if(!pFoo)
        return;
    pFoo->Release();
    pFoo = NULL;
}

IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice = ...
...
SafeRelease(pDevice);
```

Or rather, and it's serious improvement in development accuracy, use template wrappers over raw interface pointers, such as `CComPtr`.

```
CComPtr<IDirect3DDevice9> pDevice = ...
...
pDevice.Release(); // or pDevice = NULL, 
           // or nothing - automatic release on going out of scope
```